# Is there any way to limit user resources in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Can I limit user resources in MongoDB? Example of this limitation in MySQL is to limit queries per hour or connections per hour for a user. I am using mongosh to interact with MongoDB version 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

With MongodbClient you set can set up maxPoolSize to prevent a lot of queries at the same time

See https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html

> Connection pool configuration:
> maxPoolSize=n: The maximum number of connections in the connection pool
> Default value is 5

Comment: I am using mongosh to interact with MongoDB version 5.0.2 if that is what you meant about the client. I am looking for a way to limit a specific user's resources  rather than a pool or a database if that is possible.

Comment: got your question @Unsel I think you need to handle it like a tool of the system. Maybe you can create a tool schedule for every 5m to collect the resource using  make a report and trigger to our application https://www.mongodb.com/basics/how-to-monitor-mongodb-and-what-metrics-to-monitor